# SHA256 in Mysql 5.1.69

Tags: mysql, sha256, mysql-5.1

we use a MySQL 5.1.69 and want to change a table with MD5 hashed values by SQL-Script to a sha256 hashed values.

The MySQL functions MD5 and SHA1 works, but the MySQL 5.1.69 doesn't support SHA2. How can I install this function to the Database??

thank you!

Comment: By upgrading to MySQL 5.5.6

Comment: There is a SHA256 udf floating around; I chose to upgrade to more recent MySQL. I haven't tried it so I wont make it an answer: http://git.stuge.se/?p=mysql-sha256.git;a=blob;f=README;hb=refs/tags/1.0.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it out this week, and then I give you a feedback ! ;)